# React ref doesn't update on async set

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, ref

Anyone how can tell me why the ref doesn't get updated on the initial render?

I am setting the ref conditionally on the last item, which work fine if I don't set the values async.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState<Array<Number>>([]);
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [ref]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const newValues = Array(10)
        .fill(0)
        .map((item) => Math.random());
      setValues(newValues);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {values.map((value, index) => {
        const isLast = index === values.length - 1;
        return (
          <div key={value.toString()} {...(isLast && { ref: ref })}>
            {value}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-austin-49snp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't see useEffect witth dependency as `ref` executed when you populatee the `values` async is because the ref instance remains same but the current key within tthe ref object is modified.

If you track on `ref.current`, you will see the `useEffect` get executed.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [ref.current]);
```

However that is not the right approach because a change in ref is not triggering a re-render and `useEffect` is called post a re-render. What you should instead rely on as a dependency for your useEffect is a change in values which essentially causes the ref to change

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, [values]);
```

[DEMO sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-butterfly-09e9e)

Comment: Using values as dependency will give the result I expected. Thank you for the quick response :)

Comment: Was blocked on this for a while, thanks so much for the concise answer! :)